# How to make a set on plot in Matlab like on the photo - Perceptron

Tags: matlab, plot, perceptron

I have a problem to make a set and show like on this photo in attachment.

[image: photo]

Where:

[image]

Points must to be random in the range of:

[image: photo3]

Principle to set:

[image: photo2]

This is first part of exercise about perceptron. Without this I can't make other parts.

There is my code:

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

I=400;
x1=-1+rand(I/2,1)+1;
X = [0+rand(I,1)*(2*pi) [-1+rand(I/2,1)+1;
    (-1+rand(I/2,1)+1)] ]

Y = [ones((I/2),1)*sin(-1); ones(I/2,1)];


a = X(1:I/2,1);

b = X(1:I/2,2);

c = X(I/2:I,1);

d = X(I/2:I,2);

plot( a, b, 'bx');

hold on;

plot( c, d, 'go');
```

Comment: That looks like the right way to plot two sets. What is wrong?

Comment: Hello azor! Is the problem that you want to get a similar distribution as in the image?

Comment: @HermanWilén that's right.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have just modified the question

Answer (score 0):

So you already figured out how to generate the random coordinates within the area of the plot:

```
N = 400;
x1 = rand(N,1)*(2*pi);
x2 = rand(N,1)*2-1;
```

Next, you want to find the subset of points that satisfy the equation (this is the set for which `y==-1`):

```
I = abs(sin(x1)) > abs(x2);
```

`I` is a logical array, with `true` values where the condition is satisfied. You can use `I` to index into another array. For example, You can create the vector `y` like this:

```
y = ones(N,1);
y(I) = -1;
```

But you don't really need `y` to create the plot. You were already plotting two subsets, simply make the subsets using `I` as index, instead of `1:N/2`:

```
plot(x1(I),x2(I),'bx');
hold on
plot(x1(~I),x2(~I),'go');
```

The result is a plot exactly like in the question, except with `x` and `o` markers instead of `.` markers.